# relation between degree and residues

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Let $C$ a compact riemann surface of positive genus and $\omega_C$ the canonical divisor over $C$ with standard degree $2g-2$. Take on $C$ a divisor of positive degree $d$ and set $$V=H^0(C,\omega_C(D))$$ the set of section of $\omega$  with poles on $D$.
If i take an element in $V$ it has degree $2g-2+d$ but can i see an element of $V$ as a meromorphic section of $\omega_C$? And in this case  must its degree be zero?

I'm confused about two both interpretation.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin now is clear. There is another question that i cannot solve. If a take the space $H^0(C,\omega_C(2D)/ \omega_C(-2D))$ can i see an element of this as a rational section of $\omega_C$ around $D$ with poles in $D$ so an element of $H^0(C,\omega_C(2D)/ \omega_C)$?

Comment: I don't understand this notation. Do you mean $H^0(C,\omega_C(2D))/H^0(C,\omega_C(-2D))$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin With the notation $H^0(C,\omega_C(2D)/ \omega_C(-2D))$ i mean the vector space of all section of $\omega_C$ with poles on $D$ modulo those vanishing on $D$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin If you want see also this question that is related [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215917/rational-section-of-the-canonical-line-bundle-of-a-smooth-curve)

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Here the article that i'm reading where the notation appear. At the end of page 615 and at the beginning of page 616 if you need. [link](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1982-271-02/S0002-9947-1982-0654853-6/S0002-9947-1982-0654853-6.pdf)